# How to convert two datetime difference into days using mysql

Tags: mysql

Dear I have made this query it executing very well but issue is that i need days from the difference of two datetime. I am unable to calculator the days please help me to correct my query.

```
SELECT level_2_action_datetime,level_1_action_datetime,       
#unix_timestamp(level_2_action_datetime) - unix_timestamp(level_1_action_datetime) AS DifferTime_Sec,
sec_to_time(unix_timestamp(level_2_action_datetime) - unix_timestamp(level_1_action_datetime)) AS "hh:mm:ss",
(((86400 * (level_2_action_datetime - level_1_action_datetime)) / 60) / 60) / 24 AS DAYS
FROM tbl_pre_event_approval;
```

Comment: Does the calcuration of DAYS need "86400 * "?
The difference of '2020-01-02 12:00:00'-'2020-01-01 13:00:00', is it 0? or 1?

Comment: level_2_action_datetime - level_1_action_datetime = days.How  i calculate??

Answer (score 0):

The expression to calculate the days uses "unix_timestamp" and deletes "86400 *".

```
((((unix_timestamp(level_2_action_datetime) - unix_timestamp(level_1_action_datetime))) / 60) / 60) / 24 AS DAYS

e.g.
'2020-01-02 12:00:00' - '2020-01-01 13:00:00' = 0.958333333333
```

If you need to calculate days that ignore the time part, you can use the datediff function.

```
datediff(level_2_action_datetime, level_1_action_datetime) AS DAYS

e.g.
'2020-01-02 12:00:00' - '2020-01-01 13:00:00' = 1
```